# Android application stopped working

Tags: java, android

I am making android calculator app for class assignment. When i press plusminus (+/-) key first and then input any numeric key; my application stops working. But when i input numeric key and then press plusminus button it works fine.

```
else if (v.getId() == R.id.plusminus){
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(textdisplay.getText().toString());
            total = newNumber * (-1);
            textdisplay.setText(total.toString());

        }
```

Comment: What means "stop Working"? Does it Force close, and can you post a LogCat?

Comment: It seems you are getting a null pointer exception stemming from the fact that you are trying to access non-existent values by pressing the button first.

Comment: Yes A.S. It force closes.

Answer (score 1):

When your app crashes, you get errors in the logcat. It is most helpful if you post those along with your question and relevant code. However, here I am pretty sure it is a parsing/error-checking problem

> When i press plusminus (+/-) key first and then input any numeric key; my application stops working

When you press this key, you aren't checking for valid input so it is trying to parse empty text. You need to do some error-checking such as `try/catch` to check for invalid input. Something like

```
else if (v.getId() == R.id.plusminus){
  try {
    Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(textdisplay.getText().toString());
        total = newNumber * (-1);
        textdisplay.setText(total.toString());
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     // maybe show some relevant message here with a Toast or something 
     // to let the user know invalid input was entered
  }

}
```

Comment: I think catching NPE's is bad form generally.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your String from textdisplay to be empty. Because Double.parseDouble will throw a Exception when the String is empty or not numeric.

```
else if (v.getId() == R.id.plusminus){
    String number = textdisplay.getText().toString();
    if(number == null) return;  //exits function
    if(number.equals("")) return;  //exits function

    //you could do more checks here
    Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(number);
    total = newNumber * (-1);
    textdisplay.setText(total.toString());

}
```

Please also have a look at the Double Documentation here 
[LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)

Double.parseDouble(String s)

```
Throws:
NullPointerException - if the string is null
NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.
```

Comment: When i try above code, it does not force close my app which is good thing. But when plusminus key is pressed first and then number is entered it doesnot show any sign either.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(textdisplay.getText().toString());
```

is probably throwing an exception (either `NullPointer` or `NumberFormat`), so check for `textdisplay`'s value before trying to parse.